# How to read data from LAN port and display on broweser applet? sock.receive(incoming);

Tags: java, swing, sockets, applet, datagram

It works upto `sock.receive(incoming);` On my browser under applet.

After `sock.receive(incoming);` This line it is stuck. Nothing is display.

Or No Error or exception is throw even it goes away from this line.

Please Help me. Thank you in advance :)
sorry for my bad an English

This is my code.

```
 while(true)
                    {
            System.out.println("Under While loop...");
                if(incoming != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Data is not blank..." + incoming );
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Data is blank..." + incoming );
                }
              sock.receive(incoming);
            System.out.println("Hello..");
                        byte[] data = incoming.getData();
                if(data != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Data is not blank...");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Data is blank...");
                }
                        String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());


                        //echo the details of incoming data - client ip : client port - client message
                        System.out.println(incoming.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " + incoming.getPort() + " : " + s);

              if(s != "" )
             {

                String R = incoming.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " + incoming.getPort() + " : " + s;
                //lblResultTest.setText(R);
                String[] words = s.split("&");

                txtResult.setText(words[2]);
                this.getAppletContext().showDocument( this.getDocumentBase() );


             }  
                        //s = "OK : " + s;
                        //DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(s.getBytes() , s.getBytes().length , incoming.getAddress() , incoming.getPort());
                        //sock.send(dp);
                        }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) 
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        }
```

Comment: 1) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 4) *"After `sock.receive(incoming);` This line it is stuck."* How did you confirm that something is sent?

Comment: Thank you for reply @Andrew Thompson. 1) I have on Medical diagnosis device. Which will give me readings send it to the my LAN port. So i am trying to read my LAN port, So whenever data is come to my LAN port my Applet will read the data and Display to applet And This applet is placed on my ASPX or My HTML. So according to suggestion give by you on   Moving to a Plugin-Free Web(Java for web start) this approach is not suitable to my project. 2)I am sharing applet code here. So you can understand. 3) I ll try to give better clear question as possible as. 4) Point 4th ref below comment.

Comment: Point @4th When i am running my program on command prompt.  It will works properly with any interrupts. But When I am load my applet on html or ASPX it is load sucessfully. But once connection is establish it is goes under while loop but When it is come to "sock.receive(incoming);" This line nothing is happen even it is not throwing any exception or error on my java console. If it is works than "System.out.println("Hello..");" This line should be print. or Can you help me how to detect that problem. Thank you again for your response. :)

Comment: 1) Use a desktop application. As I mentioned, Applets are dead. 2) What you posted (and yes, I've already seen it) is an uncompilable code snippet, not an MCVE / SSCCE. Voting to close for lack of one. Follow the links, try to understand what they say! 3) I'll pay closer attention to code when there is a properly formatted MCVE / SSCCE. This is your problem, so it's your responsibility, not anyone elses. 4) Good to hear you confirmed it works via the command line.